# Under what circumstances can ConcurrentBag.TryTake() fail?

Tags: c#, .net, collections, concurrency

I'm thinking of using a [ConcurrentBag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779.aspx) in a program I'm writing, however I can't seem to find enough documentation on [TryTake](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381774.aspx).

I understand that the method might fail, but I can't find an explanation of the cases in which such failure might happen, and what state the collection will be left in after the failure.

If it's only in the case of another thread having already removed the item then I don't care, but what I can't really afford is the item I want to remove to still be in the collection after the call.

Can this ever be the case?

Comment: Some code (that fails) and details of exception you get would help!

Comment: @decyclone, he's not got code that fails, he's asking under what conditions the TryTake method could fail, and what the state of the collection would be after the failure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation it returns false if no item is available to take i.e. the bag is empty. As it is a thread-safe collection there should be no issues around 'empty' and multiple threads.

You have to take the documentation for `result T` as well as the `return value` into consideration:

> result T: When this method returns, result contains the object removed from the ConcurrentBag or the default value of T if the bag is empty.
>
> Return: true if an object was removed successfully; otherwise, false.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287255.aspx

Comment: sadly documentation doesnt cover any exceptions, like "Cannot access a disposed object."

Answer (score 3):

Given that you're dealing with multithreading, there's nothing to stop another thread from *adding* an item to the bag between the moment at which `TryTake` has decide to return false (and set it's return value to `default(T)`), and the moment at which the call to `TryTake` actually returns to your code.

So by the time you're able to handle the false result, there may actually be an item in the bag.

Comment: Thanks but the code involved is just making sure that a certain resource is used only once per user, thus if the user decides to send a log off shortly followed by a log on and for some reason the two happen to be processed almost simultaneously, it's not a reason for concern. Inability to log off or improper log off handling, however, would have been an issue, hence the question.